# What if question closers disguise their feelings with an official close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

**Foreword:** There's a particular question that motivated this question, but please advise whether I ought to cite it. I haven't yet, because I don't want to target specific individuals.  In my case, my question cited 3 reputable sources, but was professed to lack sufficient research, and closed. Then it was reopened even though I didn't add any more resources (but I edit the OP slightly).

---

**Actual question (TL;DR):** Suppose all 5 closers chose a close reason that  masquerades as, in order to distract from, their real reasons (eg personal bias).

Once this happens for many questions, not only the poster, but other users, must expend needless time  to petition on Meta, and to reopen the questions.
So what can be done about such closures and closers?

Comment: This should be on the meta site I think. I doubt 5 people have a personal vendetta enough to be closing questions like that...

Comment: Presumably you are talking about this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265164/intuition-if-p-then-q-not-p-or-q - I believe you're going to have to go to meta.math in order to resolve your overall question, however from my armchair perspective it truly does appear that the reason cited is the reason they voted to close. I think you've already correctly answered your own question here, *"petition on Meta"*, and then convince the community to change their standards for the type of questions you desire to ask.

Comment: @AdamDavis Thanks, but in actuality, no, that was *not* the question in my mind.

Answer (score 6):

If the close reason applies to that question (regardless of whether the people who voted to close it disliked the question for an unrelated reason) then there isn't a problem.

If the question doesn't meet the criteria given, then it can be reopened.

As to your description of your case, there is no close reason for "lacking research".  It's a reason to downvote a question, but there is no close reason for it.  If your question was re-opened due to it not meeting the criteria it was closed for, then *the system is working* and there's nothing else that needs to be done.

Comment: My OP was meant to exclude the case of your para 1. So I ask NOT about the case `If the close reason applies to that question (regardless of whether the people who voted to close it disliked the question for an unrelated reason) then there isn't a problem.`

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit You may have intended that, but it wasn't explicit, so I added a case for that.  I don't see removing it as being productive, given that what you were really interested in is also covered in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for any confusion. I just wanted to clarify my acknowledgement of that possibility.